# Change thumb tint color of Toggle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, toggle

There's [`thumbTintColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621332-thumbtintcolor) property in `UISwitch` (UIKit). What is the equivalent of this property in SwiftUI's `Toggle`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/04/customizing-toggle-in-swiftui/):

> There is no way to change the tint color of Toggle from SwiftUI, but we can use UIAppearance API from UIKit to set the tint color for all UISwitch instances across the app.

So there is no direct way to do so. However, in your `View`, you can easily set this globally with an `init`:

```swift
struct MyToggleView: View {
    init() {
        //Replace with your desired color
        UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = .orange
    }
//... (Rest of your view here)
}
```

Or, as the article suggests, you can go all the way and set up a full-on [`ToggleStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/togglestyle). See my example below, which alters the example from the docs so that you can give it a custom color:

```swift
struct ChecklistToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    var color: Color
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: configuration.isOn
                        ? "checkmark.circle.fill"
                        : "circle")
                configuration.label
            }
        }
        .tint(color) //<<< Here!
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggleIsOn = false
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Example", isOn: $toggleIsOn)
        .toggleStyle(ChecklistToggleStyle(color: .blue)) //<<< HERE! The name of the custom style you created
    }
}
```

Comment: The thumb tint colors for on and off states are different and looks like customizing the toggle style is the only way.